# MongoDB Query by Date And Sort by Distance (Mongoose + Express App)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building an Event App and would like to get All the Events on a certain date and then sort them by there location to me. How would Implement a request like this? This is what the Schema looks like:

```
var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
start_time: {
    type: Date
},
location: {
    type: {
        type: String
    },
    coordinates: []
},
});
```

I know I can query the location using the $near, i've managed to get this running. But I would like to first query for "start_time" and then sort by the events on that date by their distance to me. Any Suggestions would be very appreciated thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with this query:

```
{
    location: {
        $near : {
        $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [longitude,latitude] 
        },
        $maxDistance: 10000
        }
    },
    $and: [
        { start_time : {$gte: now, $lt: tomorrow} }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$geoNear` agg pipeline operator.   It will return docs **in order of closeness to a point you specify**.   You can tell `$geoNear` to further constraint the lookup to just your `start_time` (or any arbitrary query expression) with the `query` option in the call.   Details here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: thanks this was a little to complicated for my small example I got it to work with the $and operator and twisting the "sort" a bit. Thanks anyways